# C++ type conversion operator

Tags: c++, types, casting

I am studying operator overloading, there are some parts that are difficult to understand.

See this example code.

```
class A {
    private:
    char a;
    int b;
    double c;

public:
A(char _a = 'a', int _b = 99, double _c = 1.618) :a(_a), b(_b), c(_c){
}

public:
    operator char() const {
        cout << "operator char() called" << endl;
        return this->a;
    }

operator int() const {
        cout << "operator int() called" << endl;
        return this->b;
    }

operator double() {
        cout << "operator double() called" << endl;
        return this->c;
    }
};
int main(void) {
    A a;
    char b = a;
    int c = a;
    double d = a;

    printf("%c\n", b);
    printf("%d\n", c);
    printf("%f\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

I made this code to test for type conversion operator and expected that the appropriate function would be called for each type of data.

But the result is..

```
operator double() called
operator double() called
operator double() called
    <-- strange character is gone on board!
1
1.618000
```

I can not understand why the results are not as follows.

```
operator char() called
operator int() called
operator double() called
a
99
1.618
```

Why is double operator called when converting to char and int?

Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the `const` on the `double` conversion operator:

```
operator double() const {  // <---------------------------
        cout << "operator double() called" << endl;
        return this->c;
    }
};
```

As in your example `a` is not `const`, the double conversion is the best match. If you fix that you get the expected output.

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cDmdaAQZdlNqEkmh)

**...some opinion based PS:**

I didnt find what the core guidelines say about conversion operators, but if I had to make up a guideline for conversion operators it would be: Avoid them. If you use them, make them `explicit`. The surprising effects of implicit conversion outweigh the benefits by far.

Just as an example, consider [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Instead of offering conversion operators it has `to_string`, `to_ulong` and `to_ullong`. It is better to have your code explicit. `A a; double d = a;` is a little bit mysterious. I would have to look at the class definition to get an idea of what is really going on. On the other hand `A a; double d = a.as_double();` can do the exact same thing, but is way more expressive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and  advise!! The problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Yea so the problem is, that you made all operators const except for the double operator. I am still a bit surprised because this const just means that the operator call does not modify the class members. Still it seems that only the double operator is called for all 3. I would all 3 op's make const and then it will work properly.

If someone has an explanation why this happens, I would also like to know.
Cheers.

```
operator char() const { // here is const
    cout << "operator char() called" << endl;
    return this->a;
}

operator int() const { // here is const
    cout << "operator int() called" << endl;
    return this->b;
}

operator double() { // here is no const
    cout << "operator double() called" << endl;
    return this->c;
}
```